# Node Express.js Middleware, end Response

Tags: node.js, express, callback, httpresponse, middleware

```
validateRegister: async (req, res, next) => {

        UserModel.findOne({email:req.body.email}, (err, example) => {
            console.log(example);
            if(err) console.log(err);
            if(example) {
                res.status(400).json({message: "Email already registered!"});
                res.end() //next('route')
            }
        });
        console.log("test");
        const user = new UserModel(req.body);
        await user.save((err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: "Database issue!" });
        }); 

        next();
    },
```

Ok, I tried to insert user data if it is  not already in the database using mongoose. If the User regarding the email is already in the database the response should  be ended and the user not inserted. I tried to end the response with res.end() and next('route'), but nothing seems to work, the console.log("test") still runs.

Error:

```
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below callback function gets executed before callback gets completed and multiple res.send happened.

you can try this

```
validateRegister: async (req, res, next) => {

UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, example) => {
    console.log(example);
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });

    }
    if (example) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already registered!" });
    }
    console.log("test");
    const user = new UserModel(req.body);
    await user.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: "Database issue!" });
    });
});

next();
}
```

Or

```
validateRegister: async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    let example = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    console.log(example);
    if (example)
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already registered!" });
    console.log("test");
    const user = new UserModel(req.body);
    await user.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: "Database issue!" });
    });
    next();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add return before returning response in the case of user email already found.

What seems to happen is that your program is calling res two times

Comment: So like ```
return res.status(400).json({message: "Email already registered!"});
```
tried that before.

You're right the program calls res.json two times, because the router is defined:
```
router.post("/api", middleware.validateRegister, (req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});
```
I'm aware of that, but thats exactly the problem all the rest of the middleware code and the router code should be skipped if a user is already registered.

Comment: it seems you are using validateRegister as a middleware . according to documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) `app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  // if the user ID is 0, skip to the next route
  if (req.params.id === '0') next('route')
  // otherwise pass the control to the next middleware function in this stack
  else next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  // send a regular response
  res.send('regular')
})`

you have to use next only

Comment: if you want to throw error refer this (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: Yeah exactly, I use it as Middleware. But I cannot write next() there to skip the rest of the code block and that would also just jump to the next middlware, which should not be triggered anyway.